# MySql Query for Summarizing per Year or per Month

Tags: mysql, checksum

I have the following table structure:
table={id,DailyDate,value1,value2} with DailyDate ex. 2000-01-01

How i can get a summarize result firstly per month and secondly per year for each value?

I was trying the following but it doesn't work

```
Select Sum(Value1),Year(DailyDate),Month(DailyDate)
From table
Group by Year(DailyDate),Month(DailyDate)
Order by Year(DailyDate),Month(DailyDate)
```

ty

Comment: Perhaps you could supply sample data with desired results.  Your above query should sum the value1 field, grouping by year and month of dailydate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you're asking for is subtotals by year, try this:

```
SELECT TheSum, TheYear, COALESCE(TheMonth, CONCAT('Total Year ', TheYear))
FROM (
  SELECT
    SUM(Value1) TheSum,
    YEAR(DailyDate) AS TheYear,
    MONTH(DailyDate) AS TheMonth
  FROM table
  GROUP BY Year(DailyDate), MONTH(DailyDate) WITH ROLLUP) x
WHERE TheYear IS NOT NULL
```

The inner query uses `WITH ROLLUP` to generate subtotals by month and a grand total by year. The outer query formats the year and drops the grand total.